# Migrating fron jboss 4 to jboss 5.1.1 eap

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

please let me know what are the changes i have to do if i want to deploy the application which was running in jboss 4 and built with ejb 2.0

I am trying to deploy the same ear which was running in jboss 4 and built with ejb 2.0
but i am getting deployment exceptions.

Comment: I also did an migration to jboss-5 from jboss-4, if you can post your exceptions, then I can try to help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly big list, but thankfully it's been documented by some kind people that have done it before. Here's the JBoss community documentation on likely migration issues:

[Migration from JBoss 4 to 5](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MigrationFromJBoss4?_sscc=t)